# Animation duration in React Spring

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

I have a fairly simple fade-in scenario, where I want to control the duration of the animation. But cannot wrap around my head around how to accomplish this.

Code excerpt:

```
function BoxA() {
  return (
    <Spring from={{ opacity: 0.2 }} to={{ opacity: 1 }}>
      {props => (
        <div
          style={{
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            backgroundColor: "pink",
            color: "#fff",
            ...props
          }}
        >
          1
        </div>
      )}
    </Spring>
  );
}
```

Complete code example: https://codesandbox.io/s/n7pw660264

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to set the config property for the duration.

```
<Spring config={{duration: 5000}} from={{ opacity: 0.2 }} to={{ opacity: 1 }}>
```

Comment: This is correct, duration switches to a linear animation, in this case 5 seconds. Time based often isn't the best choice, though, see: http://react-spring.surge.sh/gotchas

Comment: Yes, it is linear by default, but you can change the easing in config as well. And I never used either of them. Most of the time spring animation just works out of the box.

Answer (score -1):

You can use delay property to control the animation,

According to documentation

> Delay in ms before the animation starts (config.delay takes precedence
>   if present) */

like this

```
<Spring from={{ opacity: 0.2 }} delay={1000} to={{ opacity: 1 }}></Spring>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/yvlyk5rplz)

[Source](https://github.com/react-spring/react-spring/blob/master/src/Spring.js#L23)

Comment: Hm, it looks like it's only waiting (delaying) 1000 ms with the animation. I was looking for defining a time unit during which the animation would gradually take effect.

Comment: @FellowStranger as far as I know there is no property to support it.